# How to read a binary file 14 bits at a time instead of 8?

Tags: c, binary, compression, bit-manipulation

I need to decompress a binary file. Since the binary file is encoded in 14 bits, I have to read 14 bits instead 8 bits to decode. But as far as I know using `getc()` to read the file only give me 8 bits each time. Are there any efficient way to achieve this? Below is a block of code which can do the job but it seems not that efficient, how can I improve it?

```
unsigned int input_code(FILE *input)
{
    unsigned int return_value;
    static int input_bit_count=0;
    static unsigned long input_bit_buffer=0L;

    while (input_bit_count <= 24)
    {
        input_bit_buffer |= 
            (unsigned long) getc(input) << (24-input_bit_count);
        input_bit_count += 8;
    }

    return_value=input_bit_buffer >> (32-BITS);
    input_bit_buffer <<= BITS;
    input_bit_count -= BITS;
    return(return_value);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Generally speaking, you should avoid read data in such small quantities because it's inefficient, although the buffering code inside the standard library and the O/S will make up for that.

A better reason would be that it can result in weird and unnatural code. Why not read 112 bits = 14 bytes at a time - that's a multiple of 8 and a multiple of 14. You can then treat the resulting buffer as 8 14-bit pieces of data. So things work out nicely.

But, if you absolutely *must* read as few bytes as possible at a time, read 16 bits, then eat (i.e. process) 14 of those, read another 16, combine them with the 2 you already read, eat 14, and repeat this process. For a hint on how you can do this sort of thing, check out base64 encoders/decoders.

Comment: When you give me the hint of 8 * 14, I thought you suggest me to read 112 bits. Why 112 bytes? I'm kind of confused.

Comment: @tonyaziten Nik has a clever idea, but he expressed it wrong. Read 14 bytes at a time and translate them into the next 8 a4-bit words.

Comment: @UncleO So the basic idea is I can just read the least common multiple of 8 and 14 at a time and process the bits later, right?

Comment: Oops - I meant to say 112 *bits* (i.e. 14 **bytes**). Sorry, my bad. Post edited.

Comment: just 56 bit is enough, it's the lowest common denominator of 14 and 8

Answer (score 1):

An overhead of a couple of instructions per input/output char or int is most likely going to be negligible. Don't try optimizing this piece of code until and unless you identify a bottleneck here.

Further, if I were you, I'd check the value returned by `getc()`. It can return `EOF` instead of data.

Also, strictly speaking, `char` (or C's byte) has `CHAR_BIT` bits in it, which can be greater than 8.

Comment: Thank you Alexey. Like you said so far I cant find an elegant way so optimize this piece of code. And for the EOF issue, since the end of file is encoded especially, the input will end when it reads special code.

Comment: The elegant way is to *not* read byte-by-byte, but to read larger blocks and process them. Hint: what's `8 * 14`?

Comment: @NikBougalis Could be. But we don't know anything about the problem, how much data is read, how much time is spent processing it, so why optimize beforehand?

Comment: @NikBougalis  Actually I thought about the Greatest Common Factor. But what type of variable should I use to store that? In the original code it uses an unsigned long to store a larger block and does bitwise operation just like you suggested.

Comment: @AlexeyFrunze true - I don't think that the reason to read more is to optimize performance, but to make the code cleaner.

Comment: @NikBougalis I could live with clean code reading the file byte by byte.

Comment: @tonyaziten you'd have to implement those operations yourself; I don't know how proficient you are with C. Alexey may be right that you would be better off doing things one or two bytes at a time, as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot read less than one byte at a time. However you can use bitmasks and shift operations to set the last two bits to `0` (if you are storing 16), and carry the two unused bits you removed for the next value. This will probably made the decoding operation a lot more complicated and expensive though.

How about decoding the values 8 by 8 (you can read 14 chars = 112 bits = 8 * 14 bits)? I have NOT tested this code, and there are probably some typos in there. It does compile but i don't have your file to test it:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    FILE *file = fopen ("...", "rt");

    // loop variable
    unsigned int i;

    // temporary buffer
    char buffer[14];

    // your decoded ints
    int decoded[8];

    while(fgets(buffer, 14, file) != NULL) {
        int cursor = 0;

        // we do this loop only twice since the offset resets after 4 * 14
        for(i = 0; i <= 4; i+= 4){
            // first decoded int is 16 bits
            decoded[i+0] = (buffer[cursor++] | (buffer[cursor++] << 8));
            // second is 2 + 8 + 8 = 18 bits (offset = 2)
            decoded[i+1] = (decoded[i+0] >> 14) | buffer[cursor++] << 2 | buffer[cursor++] << 10;
            // third is 4 + 8 + 8 = 20 bits (offset = 4)
            decoded[i+2] = (decoded[i+1] >> 14) | buffer[cursor++] << 4 | buffer[cursor++] << 12;
            // next is 6 + 8 = 14 bits (offset = 6)
            decoded[i+3] = (decoded[i+2] >> 14) | buffer[cursor++] << 6;
        }

        // trim the numbers to 14 bits
        for(i = 0; i < 8; ++i)
            decoded[i] &= ((1 << 15) - 1);
    }
    fclose(file);
}
```

Note that I don't do anything with the decoded ints, and I write on the same array over and over again, this is just an illustration. You can factorize the code more but I unrolled the loops and commented the operations so that you see how it works.

Comment: The question is tagged as C, not C++.

Comment: Oops, my bad. I removed this solution.

Comment: Thank you Thibaut. I think the original code does what you suggest, in a slightly different way.